# Cannot inspect a std::string variable in lldb

Tags: c++, clang, lldb, clang++

When I try to inspect std::string variable using LLDB, I get "error: summary string parsing error".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a{"123"};
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Process 4492 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'main', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00005555555551e9 main`main at main.cpp:6:1
   3    
   4    int main() {
   5        std::string a{"123"};
-> 6        std::cout << a << std::endl;
   7        return 0;
   8    }
(lldb) v a
(std::string) a = error: summary string parsing error
```

Additional information:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

```
$ lldb --version
lldb version 8.0.1
```

```
uname -s -r -m -o
Linux 5.3.5-arch1-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does the problem persist even if you change the variable's name?

Comment: Even if I change name it does.

Comment: what do you get for `frame variable -R a`.  This will show the implementation details of your std::string.  Your lldb should have built in formatters for libc++ and libstdc++ std::string's, it depends on which c++ library your binary is linked against which is used.  All of this should happen seamlessly though.

Comment: When I write `frame variable -R a` I get `(std::string) a = {}`

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045466/12288259) answer should resolve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lldb can't debug string when compiled by clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262055/lldb-cant-debug-string-when-compiled-by-clang)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try recompiling your source code with the `-fstandalone-debug` flag. I had this same problem when I was using lldb today and when I tried accessing the string character-by-character it threw an error that recommended compiling with this flag. After I had recompiled my binary files lldb handled strings just fine.

Note: I'm unsure if this flag works with `g++`, but I'm assuming that you compile with `clang++` if you're using lldb.

Comment: Thank you. It also works for me to add `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag.

Comment: It is a rather bad idea to add the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` compiler flag, see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24202#c9. Much better is to use either `-fstandalone-debug` or `-fno-limit-debug-info` or install and link the debug stl for your platform.